# Topological conjugacy in the case of rational rotation numbers

Tags: dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples

Is every orientation-preserving homeomorphism on  $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with rational rotation number $\alpha$ topologically conjugate to rigid rotation $R_\alpha$ ?

Comment: h is conjugate to a rotation if and only if h^q = Id for some integer q ≥ 1. Is there  an example  and a counter example for this case ?

Comment: Do you think that it is or that it is not?